# Moving "X" to a different position

Tags: java

I'm hoping that theres someone here that can help me, I'm just really struggling with my code. I'm building a simple Java game in which you can move X to another space on the board using a coordinates and I was just wondering how I can take the piece at (1,1) and move it to another spot. Thanks.

```
package ai;

/**
*
* @author x12388761
*/
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AI {

public static String[][] board = new String[10][10];
public static void addPiece(int x, int y, String r){

    board[x][y] = r;//no need for new String(), board is already made of Strings.
}
public static void showBoard(){
    //it's generally better practice to initialize loop counters in the loop themselves
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("-------------------");    
        for(int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++)
        {
            System.out.print("|"); //you're only printing spaces in the spots
            if(board[col][row] == null){
              System.out.print(" ");
            }else{
              System.out.print(board[col][row]);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("-------------------");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    addPiece(0,0," ");
    addPiece(0,1,"1");
    addPiece(0,2,"2");
    addPiece(0,3,"3");
    addPiece(0,4,"4");
    addPiece(0,5,"5");
    addPiece(0,6,"6");
    addPiece(0,7,"7");
    addPiece(0,8,"8");
    addPiece(1,0,"1");
    addPiece(2,0,"2");
    addPiece(3,0,"3");
    addPiece(4,0,"4");
    addPiece(5,0,"5");
    addPiece(6,0,"6");
    addPiece(7,0,"7");
    addPiece(8,0,"8");
    addPiece(1,1,"X");  
    addPiece(8,8,"O");
    showBoard(); 
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Would you like to go first? Yes or No");
    String goFirst = myScan.nextLine();

    if(goFirst.equals("yes") || goFirst.equals("Yes") || goFirst.equals("YES")) {
        System.out.println("You are X! Please enter the coordinates of your first move");
        String coordinate = myScan.nextLine();
        String[] parts = coordinate.split(",");


        String x = parts[0];
        String y = parts[1];



        System.out.println("Moving to (" + x +","+ y +")");

        }

    if(goFirst.equals("no") || goFirst.equals("No") || goFirst.equals("NO")) {
        System.out.println("You are O! The computer will make the first move.");

        }



}


}
```

Comment: Consider explaining your code a bit and your problem in greater detail. Understand please that we're coming to this problem completely ignorant in what your code does, what it doesn't do, what you're trying to do, and what's not working.

Comment: You'll need a while loop of some kind to keep updating the screen and prompting the user.  You'll also need to know where x/o are and where they are to be moved to

Comment: Is a space the default piece?

Comment: @JAtkin a space is an empty space which it can move into. im trying to move the letter X

Answer (score 1):

```
/** Move 1 to 2, 1 is empty after move */
public static void move(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
     board[x2][y2] = board[x1][y1];
     board[x1][y1] = " ";
}
```

This works because the `2` is set to the `1`, then `1` is set to empty. This has no checking to make sure the `2` is empty or that `1` has a piece. If you want to check for that, you need to use this:

```
/** Move 1 to 2, 1 is empty after move */
public static void move(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    if (!board[x1][y1].equals(" ") && board[x2][y2].equals(" ")) {// if 1 is not empty
                                                      // and 2 is empty
        board[x2][y2] = board[x1][y1];
        board[x1][y1] = " ";
    }
}
```

---

**Bonus:** ways to improve your code

When you ask the user if he wants to go first, you check the input using the [`String.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), which is the hard way. In this case you should use [`String.equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) i.e. `goFirst.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")`.

---

In the show board method, you use this:

```
 System.out.println(" ");
 System.out.println("-------------------");
```

The two `println`s can be joined by using the special newline char `\n` like this:

```
System.out.println("\n-------------------");
```

Comment: that code seems great but it doesnt seem to do anything, like added it in and then added a system.out.print(board) as im trying to show the new board with the new piece in it but nothing seems to be happening

Comment: That's what I get for not testing, try it now.

Comment: did you do something different? its still not doing anything?

Comment: I did, see the edit. I has 1 and 2 flipped around. If it's still not working, I would add the lines `move(1,1,Integer.parseInt(x),Integer.parseInt(y));` and `showBoard();` right after `System.out.println("Moving to (" + x +","+ y +")");`

Comment: Did you change your code since the post? I have tested this and it works fine for me... If you are using the *safe* version, try moving the x to `0,0`.

Answer (score 0):

To judge user input Yes or No , You can use equalsIgnoreCase method. This method ignore uppercase or lowercase.Like this :

```
String upper = "YES";
String lower = "yes";
upper.equalsIgnoreCase(lower);// true
```

if String lower = "YeS"; Result are also same.